# Existence of sequence of functions whose integrals tend to zero while unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find $(f_n)_{n\ge 0}$ sequence of positive integrable (lebesgue) functions (not necessarily continuous) from $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}\int_I f_n=0$$

and further more $\forall x\in I:\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{n\ge p}f_n(x)=\infty$.

When $I$ is a finite interval, I can construct the sequence by dividing $I$ into smaller and smaller pieces to make a high rectangular alternatively on these pieces (at the same time making the integral less and less). When $I=\mathbb{R}$ it doesn't work, obviously because $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't have finite length. But I cannot prove that there doesn't exist such a sequence neither.

So is there such a sequence when $I=\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq0}$ on $[0,1]$, then $g_n(x)=1/(\lfloor x\rfloor^2)f_n(\{x\})$ works on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "diagonal": Given $n$, divide the interval $[-n,n]$ in $2n^2$ intervals of length $1/n^2$, namely $I^n_i=[n+(i-1)/n^2,n+i/n^2]$, $1\leq i\leq 2n^2$, and define "rectangular functions" $f^n_i=n1_{I^n_i}$. Then $\int f^n_i=1/n$. ($1_A$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$).

The sequence $f^1_1,f^1_2,f^2_1,\ldots,f^2_8,f^3_1,\ldots,f^3_{18},\ldots,f^n_1,\ldots,f^n_{2n^2},\ldots,$ has the property you want.